# Question about Isomorphisms (between normed vector spaces)

Tags: functional-analysis

My question is regarding the following definition from functional analysis:

Let $T:X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous linear operator.
W e say $T$ is an Isomorphism if $T$ is bijective and $T^{-1}$ is continous.

In the next section, it was noted that:
Isomorphisms are linear surjective maps, such that
$\exists c,C : \forall x \in X: c||x||\leq ||Tx|| \leq C||x||.$

I don't really see how the definition implies that.

Comment: The first inequality first of all implies $T$ is injective (think why). The second inequality says $T$ is continuous. Then, now by bijectivity of $T$, the first inequality implies $T^{-1}$ is continuous (unwind definitions). Converse is similar.

Comment: When $T$ is bijective, $ c||x||\leq ||Tx||$ is same as $\|T^{-1}x\|\leq \frac 1  c \|x\|$ (which is continuity of $T^{-1}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice exercise for you is to prove the following:

> Let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces and $T:X \to Y$ linear. Then $T: X \to \operatorname{ran}T$ is bijective and the inverse
> $T^{-1}:  \operatorname{ran}T \to X$ is a continuous linear operator if and only if there is some $c>0$ with
> $$
> \| Tx \| \geq c \|x\|  \quad \forall x \in X.
> $$
> and in that case $\|T^{-1}\| \leq c^{-1}$.
> Here we view the range $\operatorname{ran}T$ of $T$ as a normed vector space with the norm of $Y$.

The assertion in your question follows from this (how?).